# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Extracted source (around line #16):

```
13:   <% end %>
14: 
15: <% create_url = {:url=>{:action=>"create"}} if @post.new_record? %>
16:         <% form_for @post, create_url do |t| %>
17:           <%= t.label :title, 'Virsraksts:' %><br />
18:           <%= t.text_field :title %><br />
19:           <%= t.label :content, 'Teksts:' %><br />
```

I am new at Ruby on Rails, so, please, help me.

This error happens when I push the edit button for post.

Comment: form_for is expecting the second argument to be a hash, try as c0deNinja suggests.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
<% form_for([:post, @post], :url => create_url) do |t| %>
```

Comment: I have modified your code to:
    <% form_for(@post, :url => create_url) do |t| %>
and now all is working, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I went through similar problem. But in my case, I have created the Message model with the generate script. This makes the model inherits from ActiveModel. I think that the persisted? method returning false combined with the ActiveModel inheritance was causing the problem. 
Then, I'll let my experience here for the case of someone else goes through this

try replace this:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
```

by this:

```
class Message
```

sorry about my english. best regards from brazil